# How to Clear a Filter - AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm very new to AngularJS and was playing with filters today. I was able to apply the `filter` filter to display only rows matching the criteria from the select menus. However, I was unable to add a "clear filter" function to the button. How can I reset the filter when the button is clicked?

In the following Plunker, you can see the code I was using in attempts achieve this:
[Plunker - AngularJS Sample](http://plnkr.co/edit/5Wz6LA)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can use `ng-click` to bind click handler to clear `query` variable within a scope.

http://plnkr.co/edit/p1DnoV

Comment: If I only want to clear filter of bedroom , I tried `$scope.query.bedroom={}` Its not working

Answer (score 29):

The `ng-click` directive can be used to set the filter model to any falsey-but-not-`false` Javascript value, such as `''`, `undefined`, `null` or `{}`.

In the following code, clicking on the `div` would reset the `customFilter` model.

```
<input type="text" ng-model="customFilter" />
<div ng-click="customFilter = undefined">
    Clear Filter
</div>
```

[Here's a link to an updated fork of your Plunker project using Angular v1.4.1](http://plnkr.co/edit/DpwlHE?p=preview)

Comment: A very quick and neat method without needing to add a click function to controller. Very simple.

Comment: That tip helped me. However I found clearing the input ng-model didn't solve my issue, I needed to clear the filter object e.g <tbody><tr ng-repeat="r in report | filter:search">.  So <button ng-click="search=undefined">Clear</button>

Comment: @JoeKir I've added an `<input type="text" ng-model="foo"> example to the Plunkr that I provided a link for in my answer.

Comment: how to apply your solution on <option value="" >Plans</option>
I am creating options for select tag by creating an array dynamically.
angular.forEach($scope.leadDetail, function(value,key){
var index = $scope.productArray.indexOf(value.Product);
if(index === -1)
{
        $scope.productArray.push(value.Product);
}

Answer (score 0):

This example will help you to clear filters if you are using the ng-table filter

```
<table ng-table="tableParams" show-filter="true" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-condensed table-hover cf">
    <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="tableData in $data">
            <td data-title="'Name'" filter="{Name:'text'}" sortable="'{Name}'" />
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

You can clear filter from **ng-click** as below

```
$scope.tableParams.parameters({ filter: {}, sorting: {}, page: 1 });
```